# Внести MySql базу данных в exe файл приложения

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных

Я создал базу данных MySql в MySql workbench и затем написал программу на C# для работы с этой базой. Я хочу создать exe файл моей программы в котором будет как программа так и сама бд с которой в приложении я работаю, чтобы приложение можно было запустить на любом пк и сразу работать с этой базой, как я могу это сделать?
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: я посоветовал бы вам мигрировать с MySql на СУБД, ориентированные на локальное использование, например, SQLite

Comment: С одной базой со всех ПК или на каждом ПК своя база? Если первое, то вам нужен доступный со всех ПК сервер, если второе, то проще всего SQLite.

Comment: Вам тут уже написали по большей части) Используйте SQLite - фактически файлик вашей БД. Можно потом с помощью ILMerge добавить вашу базу внутрь exe файла. На выходе вы получите 1 exe, но внутри с собой он будет и вашу БД таскать.